# In TWIG, is possible to get absolute url of a link with twig variables in it?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have several URLs that look as follows:

`{{domainID}}/action/{{userId}}/anotherAction`

And the latter URL points to:

`http://localhost/viewA/{{domainID}}/action/{{userId}}/anotherAction`

However, If I try to load `viewA` from `viewB` through an iframe, the link inside `viewA` instead of pointing to:

`http://localhost/viewA/{{domainID}}/action/{{userId}}/anotherAction`

it will point to:

`http://localhost/viewB/{{domainID}}/action/{{userId}}/anotherAction`

and the user will end up in a 404 page if it follows the latter.

My question is:

Is there anyway to get the absolute path of a url built that way in twig?

**EDIT**

The route definition is:

`@Route("/domain/details/{domainId}", name="domain_detailed_view")`

I tried to get the absolute path this way:

`{{ url({{domainID}}/action/{{userId}}/anotherAction) }}`

but I get this error:

> A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression
>   enclosed in parentheses

Comment: Show code of generation in template

Comment: it's the second row in my question:

<a href="{{domainID}}/view/{{userId}}/edit"> click to edit </a>

Comment: In general, why you didn't use the path and url functions of twig? For these urls, there are routes existing? May you post the route definition of it?

Comment: I tried to use them, but I get an error about hash keys, I guess because I try to use {{ }} inside of other {{ }}

Comment: you should read the docs a little bit about it, and use them like kunal in his answer

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `url` or `path` functions take the route name, not the path. You can give it an associative array as an optional second argument if the route requires parameters.

For example:

```
{{ url('domain_detailed_view', { 'domainId': domainId, 'userId': userId }) }}
```

http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/twig_reference.html

Answer (score 15):

I know it's old and answered, but with symfony 3 & twig you can do:

```
{{ app.request.getSchemeAndHttpHost() }}

/* will match even port :) i.e.
 * http://localhost:8000
 * http://localhost
 * http://example.com
 */
```

which is extremely helpful :D

Answer (score 11):

**You have two ways to do the same thing.** 
Generally you could use `url()` or path inside absolute_url function like so **absoulute_url(path(...))**. Consider the following:

```
// example 1:
{{ url('domain_detailed_view', { 'domainId': domainId, 'userId': userId }) }}
// example 2:
{{ absolute_url(path('domain_detailed_view', { 'domainId': domainId, 'userId': userId })) }}">

// note - those two do the same thing
```

Generally since Symfony 2.7 you could use absolute_url() with asserts and relative path also (relative to web/root folder). This is how you could use them to set absolute path to image in bundle and in main web folder:

[app/src/UserBundle/Resources/public/img/image.jpg]

```
<img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('bundle/user/img/image.jpg')) }}" /> // new way since 2.7 up
<img src="{{ asset('bundle/user/img/image.jpg', absolute: true ) }}" /> // old way below 2.7 removed in symfony 3.0
```

[web/css/img/some.jpg]

```
<img src="{{ absolute_url('css/img/some.jpg') }}" />
```

This is what symfony recommends to use while rendering email view.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html