# tinymce - change the url path of the uploaded images

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce

Im using laravel-tinymce-simple-imageupload so that is possible to have the tinymce plugin with image upload.

But Im not understanding where to change the url path of the uploaded images so that is used an absolute path url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, the plugin use a controller : 
https://github.com/petehouston/laravel-tinymce-simple-imageupload/blob/master/src/TinymceController.php

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $filename = 'image_'.time().'_'.$image->hashName();
    $image = $image->move(public_path('img'), $filename);
    return mce_back($filename);
}
```

So as explained here : https://github.com/petehouston/laravel-tinymce-simple-imageupload#some-notes

You just have to create a new Controller Action in your application, route it and call it as explained :

```
@include('mceImageUpload::upload_form', ['upload_url' =>'YOUR_URL_FOR_HANDLING_IMAGE_UPLOAD'])
```

Comment: Thanks! In the view I have @include('mceImageUpload::upload_form') so is necessary to add also another parameter "['upload_url' =>'YOUR_URL_FOR_HANDLING_IMAGE_UPLOAD']" but do do you know should be the url to handle image upload to have absolute url?

Comment: Please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17661854/in-twig-is-possible-to-get-absolute-url-of-a-link-with-twig-variables-in-it

Comment: Thanks, so it should be necessary to use the url() function, so what is necessary is to change the uploadImage and use in that function the url() function instead of "public_path('img'), $filename"?

Comment: 1 : create your controller with custom action
2 : set your routing
3: call your route name in your view in using url('your route name')

Comment: Thanks, Im a beginner Im not understanding this parpt " create a new Controller Action " can you explain better?

Comment: In order to create your new UploadFunction where you set the uploadPath, you've got to create a controller as explained in the doc i link you : Here is the doc of laravel to create your controller https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers

Comment: Thanks, I know how to create a new controller I just dont understand what is necessary to have in that controller.

Comment: You have to override this controller https://github.com/petehouston/laravel-tinymce-simple-imageupload/blob/master/src/TinymceController.php in order to change the upload path, you see the function in this controller ? Look, it does :  $image = $image->move(public_path('img'), $filename);     It's this who set the path of the uploaded image

Comment: Thanks, so is not possible to just change that function in that controller to instead of public_path change to "url" instead of create a new controller with a new route just to change that?

Comment: No, the 'url' is for the twig view, the 'url' in the twig view will call the controller action. In the controller action, you will specify where the picture will be saved physically on your server... (with move)